# Ajax Jquery change div value itself

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, reload

I have a page that call some google chart graphs. Each of these graphs have it's own filters:

- Chart 1: Selling: per month, per year;
- Chart 2: Customers: type of products ...);

So i call each of them through an ajax call (by click). But now comes the trouble: i need to filter the charts through an another ajax call, inside the page i've already call.

Basically i just need to change the $_GET value and refresh the div that were called first.

**working**

**MAIN.PHP**

```
//receives the chart content
<div id="resultado"> 
  <!-- Google Chart -->
</div>     
 <pre>
//call the chart by click event
<a href="#" id="grafico1">click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
 });
 var ajax_load = "<img src='images/preloader.gif' class='loading' />";
 var carregaUrl = "graficos/vendas.php";

 $("#grafico1").click(function(){
    $("#resultado")
    .html(ajax_load)
    .load(carregaUrl, "id=<?php echo $id; ?>");
 });
</script>
```

**vendas.php**

```
<select id="getValue">
    <option value="0">Selecionar</option>
    <option value="121">John</option>
    <option value="131">Rubia</option>
    <option value="141">Tony</option>
</select>
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var ajax_load = "<div id='grafico-load' class='span14'><img src='images/preloader.gif' alt='carregando...' class='loading' /></div>";
var carregaUrl = "graficos/vendas.php";
$("#getValue").change(function(){
var v = $('select#getValue').val();
    $("#resultado")
        .html(ajax_load)
        .load(carregaUrl, "idg="+v);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are making a new call based on what value? A textbox? A hidden field? Or what?

Comment: i'm making the call with a select (on change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// However you opt to do so, change the value of our `GET` url
carregaUrl = "graficos/newurlhere.php";

// once the value is updated, your existing `click` function 
// will load its result in `$("#resultado")`

$("#grafico1").click(function(){
    $("#resultado")
    .html(ajax_load)
    .load(carregaUrl, "id=<?php echo $id; ?>");
});
```

If you want to update the value and run the load function without the `click` event, you can do that, too:

```
$("#resultado").html(ajax_load)
               .load(carregaUrl, "id=<?php echo $id; ?>");
```

Comment: wow, thanks couzzi o/ it's working, i also incremented the code, calling by radio or select o/